# loop fails to terminate once conditions are met

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to get my function to end the loop once it hit the return clause but it fails to do so.
Explanations rather than direct code editing would be appreciated.

```
def Menu():
    UserMenu = True
    print (""" 
        U.Create a Username
        E.Run Exponential Calculator
        Q.Exit/Quit 
        """)
    while UserMenu not in ("U", "E", "Q"):
        print("\n Error: Choice must be U, E or Q")
    return UserMenu

# Function designed to retrieve first name only from fullname entry.
def get_first_name(name):
    first=[""]
    i = 0 
    while i < len(name) and name[i] !=" ":
        first += name[i]
        i += 1
    return name[:i]

# Function designed to retrieve first initial of last name or first initial of first name if only one name input.
def get_last_initial(name):
    j = len(name) - 1 
    while j >= 0 and name[j] !=" ":
        j-=1
    return name[j+1]


# Function that generates username based upon user input.
def get_username():
    name = raw_input("Please enter your Full Name: ") 
    username = get_first_name(name) + get_last_initial(name) 
    return username.lower()



# Function to generate exponential numbers based upon usser input.
def print_exponential(): 
    base = int(raw_input("Please select a base number: \n")) 
    power = int(raw_input("Please select a power number: \n")) 
    exponential = 1 
    while power>0: 
        exponential = exponential * base 
        print base 
        if power >1:
            print "*",
        power = power -1 
    return "=%d" % exponential

print Menu()
while UserMenu != "Q":
    if UserMenu is "U":
        UserMenu = raw_input("Please enter your Full Name: ")
        print "your username is %s" % get_username()
    else:
        print print_exponential()
    print Menu()
```

This is the whole program, hope it helps!

Comment: `UserMenu` will forever not be equal to `("U", "E", "Q")` because you set it as `UserMenu = True`. You need to use `input` (python 3) or `raw_input` (python 2) for someone to interact with your program

Comment: Your edit has made this more complicated. What are you intending for `print Menu()`?

Comment: Also, when doing string comparison, use `==` instead of `is`. They are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the value of `UserMenu` inside the loop, or else entering the loop will inherently be an infinite loop:

```
def Menu():
    UserMenu = raw_input(""" 
        U.Create a Username
        E.Run Exponential Calculator
        Q.Exit/Quit 
        """)
    while UserMenu not in ("U", "E", "Q"):
        UserMenu = raw_input("\n Error: Please input only U, E or Q:")
    return UserMenu


...
all your other functions
...

user_choice = Menu()
while user_choice != "Q":
    if user_choice == "U":
        print "your username is %s" % get_username()
    else:
        print_exponential()
    user_choice = Menu()
```

By getting new input in the loop, it will be able to meet the criteria that controls the loop.  The loop you wrote will just print then check `UserMenu` again without changing it, so the loop will never exit.

Comment: It would be sligtly better if you didn't copy pasted the message in the loop. But you're answer is still wrong.

Comment: whoops, forgot to change `!=` to `not in`, the code should work now.  The point is that the control condition needs to be updated within the loop.

Comment: At this point I think it would be good if you could expand a bit on what went wrong here. The OP had 6 (I think) answers that all missed the mark. The fact is that `print` is visual only so they need to prompt for input. Also, if this is Python 2 then it will not behave as expected.

Comment: And, looking at the last edit on question, this is indeed python 2.

Comment: @Will thanks for the info, that has actually helped me understand the concept a bit better. However now that I have made your changes all my input choices are coming up not defined!

Comment: Where is the explanation for `raw_input`? You now have a mix. @DarrenMacis swap `input` for `raw_input` in all cases.

Comment: @DarrenMacis  I edited it again to correct the bottom of the script where you're calling `Menu` and your other functions.  If you're still having issues or need more explanation, open a new question.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for that, I think I've got it all in python 2 now

Comment: @Will I am a bit confused as to the purpose of the raw_input for the UserMenu = raw_input("\n Error: Please input only U, E or Q:"). all I want to do there is print the error message and then prompt them for another input after.

Comment: `raw_input("some message")` will print `some message` (or whetever you put in the parameter) then take input returned as a string.  as for `input()` ve `raw_input`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort out my problem using the following code.

```
def Menu():
    result = raw_input (""" 
        U.Create a Username
        E.Run Exponential Calculator
        Q.Exit/Quit 
        """).upper()
    while result not in ("U", "E", "Q"):
        print("\n Error: Please input only U, E or Q:")
        result = raw_input (""" 
        U.Create a Username
        E.Run Exponential Calculator
        Q.Exit/Quit 
        """).upper()
    return result


# Function designed to retrieve first name only from fullname entry.
def get_first_name(full_name):
    i = 0 
    while i < len(full_name) and full_name[i] !=" ":
        i += 1
    return full_name[:i]

# Function designed to retrieve first initial of last name or first initial of first name if only one name input.
def get_last_initial(full_name):
    j = len(full_name) - 1 
    while j >= 0 and full_name[j] !=" ":
        j-=1
    return full_name[j+1]


# Function that generates username based upon user input.
def get_username():
    username = get_first_name(full_name) + get_last_initial(full_name) 
    return username.lower()



# Function to generate exponential numbers based upon user input.
def print_exponential(): 
    base = int(raw_input("Please select a base number: \n")) 
    power = int(raw_input("Please select a power number: \n")) 
    exponential = 1 
    while power>0: 
        exponential = exponential * base 
        print base 
        if power >1:
            print "*",
        power = power -1 
    return "=%d" % exponential

choice = Menu()
while choice != "Q":
    if choice == "U":
        full_name = raw_input("Please enter your Full Name:")
        print "your username is %s" % get_username()
    else:
        print print_exponential()
    choice = Menu()
```